# Internationalization in a monorepo

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, monorepo

I have an app (just frontend) whose code is structured in a monorepo. There are separate packages for each custom widget. I would also like to have one package with all the translations. In this way, if another package need a translation I just need to import that package. So I created the translation package and in its main file I just wrote (here I use `intl`):

```dart
export 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
```

Now, if I import that package in another package and I import the file with:

```dart
import 'package:l10n/l10n.dart';
```

It tells me that that import is not used and gives me error when I use the translation with `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.foo`

Comment: Hi Damien, have you found better solution?
I get ```Undefined name 'AppLocalizations'.``` even after exporting `export 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'
    show AppLocalizations;` and then importing the package containing it `import 'package:l10n/l10n.dart';`

Comment: Hi @Chris, check out the answer that I just added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to export generated file by design ([check out this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109606)). The best solution that I've found to fix my problem is the following:

1. Create a translation package inside your project, like in `packages/translations` and add that package to the `pubspec.yaml` of your your main project. Like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  translations:
    path: packages/translations
```

2. In that package create a `l10n.yaml` file like this:

```
arb-dir: lib
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
synthetic-package: false
```

3. If you are working in a git repo, add `packages/translations/lib/app_localizations*.dart` in your `.gitignore`
4. Now if you run `flutter packages get && flutter gen-l10n` in that translations packages all the translations  will be automatically generated (assuming they are in `packages/translations/lib/app_xx.arb`)
5. Now you can import the translation file from you main package with `import 'package:translations/app_localizations.dart';`

The only drawback is that the translations are not automatically generated when you type `flutter pub get` ([see this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84979)). In order to regenerate them you have to type `flutter gen-l10n` inside the `translations` package every time. The solution could be improved by using a tool for managing Dart monorepo projects like [melos](https://melos.invertase.dev).

An example implementation of what I described (including melos) could be found in [this github repo](https://github.com/ferraridamiano/ConverterNOW)

Answer (score 0):

If you use VScode (don't know for other editors) you have to manualy import the generated translation package:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
```

Comment: Manually? I would expect that if I export a genereated file and then I import it from another package it works (just like any other non generedated file). What's the issue here? To me it seems a major blocker for large projects. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! 
Honestly, i have not try to find a solution for this. 
Don't forget to checkmark the answer.